# Django ORM - Filter Related Objects

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I apologize if this is a duplicate, but I was unable to find any other SO posts that address this matter. I have models like so:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    pass

class Interest(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name='interests')
    is_cool = models.BooleanField()
```

I know that I can find all people who have cool interests like so:

```
Person.objects.filter(interests__is_cool=True)
```

However, what I really want is to get only their cool interests when I get the `Person` object. I know that I could always pluck the related queryset out and operate on it, like so:

```
interests = person.interests.filter(is_cool=True)
```

but I cannot assign it back to the person instance since the relationship is reversed.  To summarize, the goal is to use the ORM directly to filter the `Interest` objects being returned in the `person.interests` queryset.

Comment: I think that would probably break most design principles: you typically do not want to filter in a way that alters the related managers as well. You can of course make a manager like `cool_interests`, etc. So unless by manually hacking an `.interests` into a specific person, this sounds like a bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is to define a method or property on the model:

```
def cool_interests(self):
    return self.interests.filter(is_cool=True)
```

Comment: In this case, the filtering is dynamic and based on user provided input (the sample code is just a contrived example). and hence cannot be a property.